# Givens rotation vs 2x2 Householder reflection

Tags: matrix-factorization

The usual story of Givens rotations vs Householder reflections is that Householder reflections are better if you want to map a long vector to $e_1$, while Givens is better if you want to map a 2-vector to $e_1$. However, I can't find a reference which explains why Givens is better in the 2-vector case. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but I want to add some notes:

The following c code applies a rotation:

```c
// Apply rotation: [x] = [c  s] * [x]
//                 [y]   [-s c]   [y]
void apply_rotation(int n, float* x, float* y, float c, float s){
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
      float temp = c * x[i] + s * y[i];
      y[i] = -s * x[i] + c * y[i];
      x[i] = temp;
   } 
}
```

This requires 6n flops, or to be more precise, 4n multiplications and 2n additions. On modern cpu's, there is something called a fused multiply-add (FMA), which executes a multiplication and an addition. Such an instruction is about as fast as a pure multiplication (and often just as fast). This lets us reclassify the cost as: 4n FMA instructions.

The following c code applies a second order reflector:

```c
// apply reflector:
//[x] = [x] - tau * [1 ] * [1, v1] * [x]
//[y]   [y]         [v1]             [y]
void apply_reflector(int n, float* x, float* y, float tau, float v1)
{
    float tv0 = tau;
    float tv1 = tau * v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        float refsum = x[i] + y[i] * v1;
        x[i] -= refsum * tv0;
        y[i] -= refsum * tv1;
    }
}
```

Ignoring the two multiplications at the start, this requires 6n flops (3n multiplications and 3n additions). Importantly, this can be implemented using just 3n FMA instructions.

I think the reason why researchers favor rotations over small reflections is a combination of habit and software. The efficient application of a reflector I presented here is usually not available. Instead, people use a function which applies a variable size reflector to a variable amount of vectors and those are slower than a simple rotation.

Extra note:
In the vast majority of cases, you won't notice the difference between a rotation and a small reflector. Usually, the cost of loading and storing the two vectors will be much larger.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this variant but the math checks out. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @njuffa i think you're referring to rotations vs large order reflectors. This post is about small order reflectors.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you don't apply these matrices to a single vector; you apply them to a $m\times n$ matrix, where $n$ is large, so you can amortize the cost of computing the various coefficients. Applying a Householder reflector to a vector (with the formula $x \mapsto x - vv^Tx$) costs $4m-1$. Applying a Givens rotation works only for $m=2$, and costs $6$ operations, which is cheaper.

EDIT: To apply the Householder transformation, you could instead form the $2\times 2$ matrix $Q = I-vv^T$ and apply that to a vector, as suggested by @gTcV in the comments, for 6 operations. But it's not complicated to see that at this point $Q$ is essentially a Givens rotations with two signs swapped, so that's not really anything different from Givens transformations.

Comment: The cost of applying a Givens rotation is that of a 2x2 matrix-vector product, and clearly applying a Householder reflection can't be more expensive than that because I can represent the Householder reflector as a dense 2x2 matrix. I therefore don't see how the performance argument works out.

Comment: @gTcV Good point -- I was referring to Householder reflectors when applied in the usual form $I-vv^T$; if you convert them to a $2\times 2$ matrix and apply them directly then the cost becomes the same.